# ReactNative, typescript absolute path setting -> importing is working fine but warning comes up in vscode

Tags: typescript, react-native, tsconfig

I'm using typescript and setup absolute path usage through tsconfig.json and babel.config.js.
It totally worked fine but suddenly vscode emits some error.
Strangely, importing components works perfectly fine. I guess it's a problem from vscode but I don't know how to solve the problem.

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, // turn on allowSyntheticDefaultImports
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./src/*"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"]
}
```

And this is my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins: [
        [
            'module-resolver',
            {
                root: ['./src'],
                extensions: ['.ios.ts', '.android.ts', '.ts', '.ios.tsx', '.android.tsx', '.tsx', '.jsx', '.js'],
                alias: {
                    '@': './src',
                },
            },
        ],
        'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
};
```

And these are one of the importing codes and an error.

```
import {ScaledSDText as Text} from '@/components/common/ScaledText';
```

> Cannot find module '@/components/common/ScaledText' or its corresponding type declarations.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewjys.png)

And auto complete for importing is not working anymore. What is the problem? :(
please help me..

I don't know but maybe problem came from vscode settings.

Comment: I tried reloading the editor one more time, and then the problem solved.. 
But I still would be appreciate if you give me any clues or tips regarding this issue :)

Comment: Often that is the solution. Changing the tooling in this way can require reloading the editor.